# How to copy 1 Environment Lighting Setting from a scene to apply to another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have multiple scenes in my game and I want all of them to have the same Environment Lighting Setting but I can't seem to find a away to just copy one of the Environment Lighting Setting that I like from a scene that I have made to add to another scene. Is this even possible or do I have to redo all of the setting by hand for all of the other scenes.
[image]

Comment: It **is** possible … but it was a pain. I did it a couple of years ago. I ended up using refelection to copy all of the fields to create a JSON file, then used a JSON file on each new scene that I wanted a new set of lighting settings. There was a reason why I did that, but I can’t recall off the top of my head. ‍♂️